# Extracting Func<> from Expression<>

Tags: c#, func, linq-expressions

I wanna extract the Func<> from the following Expression :

```
Expression<Func<IQueryable<Entity>, IOrderedQueryable<Entity>>> order = q => q.OrderByDescending(c=>c.FullName);

Func<IQueryable<Entity>, IOrderedQueryable<Entity>> orderFunc = ?
```

How can I do it?

**Edit :**

And how can we convert `Func<IQueryable<Entity>, IOrderedQueryable<Entity>>` to `Expression<Func<IQueryable<Entity>, IOrderedQueryable<Entity>>>` ?

Comment: `orderFunc = order.Compile()`.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy: Please write it to new post form marking as answer

Comment: Apologies - I didn't have enough time to write up a full answer, but still wanted to help. Servy has already provided an answer which addresses your edit as well as the original question, which is better than what I would have written anyway.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `Compile` method to turn any `Expresstion<TDelegate>` into a `TDelegate`.

---

There is no way to convert a delegate into an `Expression<TDelegate>`.  The detailed information about what makes up the expression was lost when it was compiled into a delegate.

You could, in theory create an expression who's body does nothing but invoke the given delegate, by doing something like this:

```
Func<int> function = () => 42;
Expression<Func<int>> expression = () => function();
```

but such an expression isn't really useful.  There really isn't any meaningful information inside of that expression.  So while it's technically possible, it's never really practical.