# How to set ValidationMessage<TValue>.For Property dynamically in Blazor?

Tags: c#, validation, blazor, blazor-webassembly

This Section of the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#validation-summary-and-validation-message-components) describes, how to display Validation Messages.

```
<ValidationMessage For="() => Parameters.PropertyA"></ValidationMessage>
```

### How can the ValidationMessage.For Property be set dynamically?

Since `For` is of type `Expression<Func<TValue>>`, I want to pass a Func instead, but this doesn't compile:

```
[Parameter]
public Func<string> PropertyLocator { get; set; }

<ValidationMessage For="PropertyLocator"></ValidationMessage>
```

this compiles, but Validation Messages won't be resolved correctly

```
<ValidationMessage For="() => PropertyLocator"></ValidationMessage>
```

I also tried to make the Component generic, such that it knows about the `Parameters` Type:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

public partial class MyComponent<TParam>
{
    [Parameter]
    public TParam Parameters { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Func<TReportParam, string> PropertyLocator { get; set; }
}


@using System.Linq.Expressions
@typeparam TParam
<ValidationMessage For="@((Expression<Func<string>>)(() => PropertyLocator(this.Parameters)))"></ValidationMessage>


<MyComponent TParam="MyParameters" Parameters="BindToSomeValue" PropertyLocator="(parameters) => parameters.PropertyA" />
```

But this leads to the following run-time exception:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: The provided expression contains a InvocationExpression1 which is not supported.
> FieldIdentifier only supports simple member accessors (fields,
> properties) of an object. System.ArgumentException: The provided
> expression contains a InvocationExpression1 which is not supported.
> FieldIdentifier only supports simple member accessors (fields,
> properties) of an object.    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.FieldIdentifier.ParseAccessor[String](Expression`1
> accessor, Object& model, String& fieldName)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.FieldIdentifier.Create[String](Expression`1
> accessor)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.ValidationMessage`1[[System.String,
> System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].OnParametersSet()    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallOnParametersSetAsync()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()

Comment: If the property is of type `Expression<Func<TValue>>` why are you trying to pass a `Func<TValue>` to it? Shouldn't it just be `public Expressiona<Func<string>> PropertyLocator { get; set; }`?

Comment: Please notice that `public partial class MyComponent<TParam>
{
    [Parameter]
    public TParam Parameters { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Func<TReportParam, string> PropertyLocator { get; set; }
}` doesn't compile. Where does `TReportParam` comes from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created a small sample page.

The model uses `DataAnnotations` as the validation mechanism.

```
    public class DemoInputModel
    {
        [Required]
        public String PropertyOne { get; set; }

        [MinLength(2)]
        public String PropertyTwo { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(5)]
        public String PropertyThree { get; set; }
    }
```

On the page, the model is initialized and set as the edit context. We have three text inputs and a select box. The select box can be used to toggle the validation message. If the value is of the select box is changed, a new expression is assigned to the `ValidationMessage`.

```
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
@using System.Linq.Expressions;

@page "/test"


<h1>ValidationMessageTest</h1>

<EditForm Model="_model">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />

    <ValidationMessage For="ValidationResolver"></ValidationMessage>

    <InputText @bind-Value="_model.PropertyOne" />
    <InputText @bind-Value="_model.PropertyTwo" />
    <InputText @bind-Value="_model.PropertyThree" />

    <InputSelect @bind-Value="SelectedValidationProperty">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </InputSelect>

    @*<ValidationSummary />*@

</EditForm>


@code {

    private DemoInputModel _model = new DemoInputModel
    {
        PropertyOne = "Test",
        PropertyTwo = "42",
        PropertyThree = "Math.PI",
    };

    private String _selectedValidationProperty;

    public String SelectedValidationProperty
    {
        get => _selectedValidationProperty;
        set
        {
            _selectedValidationProperty = value;
            ChangeValidator(value);
        }
    }

    public Expression<Func<String>> ValidationResolver { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        SelectedValidationProperty = "1";
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    public void ChangeValidator(String value)
    {
        switch (value)
        {
            case "1":
                ValidationResolver = () => _model.PropertyOne;
                break;
            case "2":
                ValidationResolver = () => _model.PropertyTwo;
                break;
            case "3":
                ValidationResolver = () => _model.PropertyThree;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Did you mean something like this? It gets slightly more complicated if your model doesn't have only strings, like in the example. A "quick" workaround could be to have an `Expression` for each possible type.

Under the hood, the expression is used to create a `FieldIdentifier`. The   `FieldIdentifier` is then used to get the corresponding property/field from the `EditContext` to check the validation status. Hence, you are constrained in what to choose for the expression. The error message *FieldIdentifier only supports simple member accessors (fields, properties) of an object* gives a good indication of this limitation.

Comment: Yea I was thinking about creating FieldIdentifiers myself. Thanks for the Example. It pretty much resembles, what I have already coded myself ;)

I'll accept this answer, because I think It might also help others to achieve this behavior.

Comment: Thanks. Building a ```CustomFieldIIdentifier``` class sounds very interesting. Maybe, you can share your solution once you are finished?

Comment: Since you asked, I did some more research on this topic. It seems like I have found the Solution for the problem, the way it propably is intended by the blazor team. [check it out :)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66262767/4099159)

Answer (score 1):

> I want to pass a Func instead

Why? If there isn't a specific reason why you should pass `Func<TValue>` instead of `Expression<Func<TValue>>`, just have the parameter

```
[Parameter]
public Expression<Func<string>> PropertyLocator { get; set; }
```

If you want only a `Func<>` because you are going to reuse it for something else other than the `For` parameter of `ValidationMessage`, you can take a look at [Extracting Func<> from Expression<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20368638/extracting-func-from-expression) to get a `Func<>` from the `Expression<Func<string>> PropertyLocator`.

If you really want to pass a `Func<>`, maybe you will get some problems to transform when trying to [convert a .net Func to a .net Expression<Func>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767733/converting-a-net-funct-to-a-net-expressionfunct).

Comment: yes. thats about it. There's no specific reason not to use `Expression<Func<string>>`

Answer (score 1):

After some research I stumbled about the following blazor feature:

#### The *holy* trinity of blazor bindings

Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60659712/4099159).

In short, if a `[Parameter]` is bound with the follwoing syntax...

```
<MyComponent @bind-Value="My.Binding.Path" />
```

... it not only supports [two-way bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0), but it also sets a locator expression.

```
[Parameter]
public string Value { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public EventCallback<string> ValueChanged { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public Expression<Func<string>> ValueExpression { get; set; }
```

*you may use any type, instead of* `string`

since the value of the `ValueExpression` is set automatically, you can use this behavior to display the validation message for the bound property. Simply add the `ValidationMessage` Component to your component with the expression.

```
<ValidationMessage For="ValueExpression" />
```

---

#### A little extra

If you're building a Component that supports Validation (which at this point, I assume you are). The following might also be interesting for you.

Not only can you use the *holy trinity* to display validationmessages, but also to create Components supporting validation. There are many articles covering this topic.

In short:

- Build your component
- Notify field changes on the `EditContext` whenever needed

To make the above created `MyComponent`s `Value` Property support validation, just follow these steps.

Define a `CascadingParameter` EditContext, this gets the current EditContext, usually from the `EditForm` Component. Also note that the EditContext may not be set, if there's no CascadingValue. For example if the Component isn't placed inside an `EditForm`:

```
[CascadingParameter]
public EditContext? EditContext
```

Define a property to store a `FieldIdentifier` and set it when parameters are set.

```
public FieldIdentifier? FieldIdentifier { get; private set; }

public override async Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
{
    await base.SetParametersAsync(parameters);

    if (this.EditContext != null && this.DateExpression != null && this.FieldIdentifier?.Model != this.EditContext.Model)
    {
        this.FieldIdentifier = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.FieldIdentifier.Create(this.DateExpression);
    }
}
```

Trigger the validation for the Field whenever you need (usually after the invocation of `ValueChanged`):

```
this.Value = value;
this.ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(this.Value);
if (this.FieldIdentifier?.FieldName != null)
{
    this.EditContext?.NotifyFieldChanged(this.FieldIdentifier!.Value);
}
```

Comment: For readability and consistency with the rest of the post, I think you want to change that last line of Set Parameters Async to: this.FieldIdentifier = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.FieldIdentifier.Create(this.ValueExpression);

Comment: Same also in if clause